# PySpark UD(A)F for aggregation is very slow

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am experimenting SPARK 2.4.6 with python for one of our requirements.

```
Sample data
device1, timestamp, parameter1, value
device1, timestamp, parameter2, value
device1, timestamp, parameter3, value
device1, timestamp, parameter4, value
device2, timestamp, parameter1, value
device2, timestamp, parameter2, value
device2, timestamp, parameter3, value
device2, timestamp, parameter4, value
```

With this data, I want to perform a custom aggregation using all the parameters from one device for a given timestamp. So I group using deviceName and timestamp and then use UDF for aggregation. I tried two approaches with following schema.

```
#Create spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("paramAggregation").getOrCreate()

#Defince schema and load data
param_schema = [StructField('deviceName', StringType()),
                StructField('timeStamp', TimestampType()),
                StructField('parameterName', StringType()),
                StructField('paramValue', IntegerType()]
df_struct = StructType(fields=param_schema)
df = spark.read.csv("<path>/paramdata.csv", df_struct)
```

In first approach I used grouped aggregate with Pandas

```
#@pandas_udf(df.schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def pandaUDAFAggregation(group_input):
    ..
    ..
    return output_frame

#Perform aggregation
start = time.time()
df.groupBy("deviceName", "timeStamp").applyInPandas(pandaUDAFAggregation, df.schema).show()
diff = time.time() - start
print("Time taken - ", diff)
```

Then in second approach, I tried following:

```
def dfUDFAggregation(paramNames, values):
    ..
    ..
    return aggValue
dfUDFAggregation = udf(dfUDFAggregation, StringType())

#Perform aggregation
start = time.time()
df.groupBy("deviceName", "timeStamp").agg(dfUDFAggregation(collect_list("parameterName"), collect_list("paramValue"))).show()
diff = time.time() - start
print("Time taken - ", diff)
```

For a 350 records data set, first approach takes almost a minute and the 2nd approach almost 6 minutes. Please note that its not the aggregate function that is taking time. Even if that function is kept empty with some hard coded return, it take this much time. The interval between subsequent calls to the aggregate function is taking lots of time.

With the same code, if I use built-in aggregate functions, its very fast and there is no issues.

Is there anything that needs to be done differently for user defined aggregate functions? Any suggestions?

Comment: Converting between Spark dataframe and pandas dataframe can take some time. Do you have pyarrow enabled? See: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-pyspark-pandas-with-arrow.html

Comment: @ScootCork Yes, I tried that and it does not make much difference. Btw, out of the two approaches Pandas was the faster one...So i think there is some other issue. Thanks

Comment: @RajeshJose Did you get a solution/work around for this problem ?